Integartion an interactive 3D mapbox into the A-frame
I'm desging an AR field trip geologist using WebXR(htmal, javascript and a-frame), so I'm tryiny to render an interactive 3D mapbox on my A-frame, and EVERYTIME I endup with a flat map anyone have an idea about the prolem and how to solve it
